# Running evosuite generated tests in Eclipse

Tags: evosuite

I have generated the test cases using evosuite from the command line in Linux.
I try to execute the tests in Eclipse. I have imported in my project the  evosuite-standalone-runtime-0.2.0.jar.

All the imported classes regarding evosuite are marked with the error sign.

```
import org.evosuite.runtime.EvoRunner;
import org.evosuite.runtime.EvoRunnerParameters;
import org.evosuite.runtime.testdata.EvoSuiteFile;
import org.evosuite.runtime.testdata.EvoSuiteLocalAddress;
import org.evosuite.runtime.testdata.EvoSuiteRemoteAddress;
import org.evosuite.runtime.testdata.EvoSuiteURL;
```

I don't understand this. It looks like these classes are unknown even though are in the imported jar file.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

> Right button in your project-->build path--> Add External Archives
>   (select evosuite-0.2.0.jar)

**Do not forget to put the two classes in the project.** (ESTest.java and ESTest_scaffolding)

I hope this helps.